# Homebrew Cask download failure. SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Tags: command-line, homebrew, ssl

I am trying to install [NetLogo](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/) via [Homebrew Cask](https://brew.sh). I run the following command:

```
brew cask install netlogo
```

Homebrew starts the download but immediately throws the following error:

```bsh
==> Downloading https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/6.1.1/NetLogo-6.1.1.dmg
#=#=-#  #                                                                     
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
Error: Download failed on Cask 'netlogo' with message: Download failed: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/6.1.1/NetLogo-6.1.1.dmg
```

I am understanding that it is happening due to expired certificate on the website hosting NetLogo installer.

Is there a way to work around this issue? For example is there an argument that could be passed to `brew` command to make it ignore the error? or provide a resolution? or can I manually download the DMG and place it in the Homebrew cache directory so that Homebrew skips downloading when running the install command?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is documented [here](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/burp-suite-cask-wont-install-curl-ssl-error/7930), see also https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2020-06/0010.html and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232445/https-connection-to-specific-sites-fail-with-curl-on-macos.

The proposed solution is to set `HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL`

```
HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1 brew cask install netlogo
```

If you run Catalina you can use

```
export CURL_SSL_BACKEND=secure-transport
```

to have `curl` not use LibreSSL (which seems to have the issue).

You can also remove the entry for `AddTrust` from `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` (it's the first entry in the file, just remove all which expired end of May 2020).

Comment: Really appreciate your helpful pointer and explanation. I realize I have not carefully browsed through the Homebrew community discussion forums.

Comment: @Seamus You might be interested in this as well :-)

Comment: `HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1` worked for me.  `CURL_SSL_BACKEND=secure-transport` did not.   I did not try editing cert.pem

Comment: There needs to be semicolon between your two commands. Basically the answer is, _first_ `HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1`, and _then_ try your install whatever it is.

Comment: @matt There doesn’t need to be (otherwise there would also need to be an `export` in front. `ENV=var cmd` is valid shell syntax for setting `ENV` only for `cmd` (see `Simple commands` in `man bash`, "A  simple command is a sequence of optional variable assignments followed by blank-separated words and redirections").

Answer (score 10):

For people that don't have a brewed installed `curl`, the accepted answer is not sufficient because it's impossible to install the *homebrew* `curl` with invalid certificates (since `brew install` uses the *system* `curl` when the *homebrew* `curl` is not available). One way to get around this is to pass the `--insecure` flag to the *system* `curl` when installing the *homebrew* `curl`, through the `~/.curlrc` file. However, one needs to define the `HOMEBREW_CURLRC=1` environment variable prior to this:

```
edit or create ~/.curlrc file and add "--insecure" to it then:
$ HOMEBREW_CURLRC=1 brew install curl
delete ~/.curlrc file or remove the "--insecure" from it
$ [HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1 if needed] brew install whatever
```

[Source](https://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2019/07/homebrew-download-curl-60-ssl-certificate-problem.html)

Comment: I am a bit confused by this sitiuation. Your steps helped in my situation. Additionally I added `# Fix broken macOS curl`
`if [ -d "/usr/local/opt/curl/bin" ] ; then
    export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH";
fi;
export HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1
` to my `~/.bash_profile`. I am still on mojave. Will see if this issue gets solved when I finally upgrade to a more recent MacOS.

Comment: thanks this works!

Answer (score 2):

When I access the URL from here, the SSL certificate is not expired. I would suggest to retry the command now to see if it works.

If you still get the same error, I would check the date & time settings on your computer - they might be incorrect.

If they're correct, I would suggest manually installing the program. The Cask code for this specific app is very simple, so you can easily do it manually.

Simply open this URL in a browser:

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/6.1.1/

Download the DMG file for macOS. Double-click the DMG to open it, and install like any other application.

UPDATE: Given the comment below that the question was not asked for the purpose of getting NetLogo installed, but rather to understand why the problem occurs and how to resolve it properly:

When you look closer at the TLS communication with the download server (ccl.northwestern.edu), we see that the problem is actually with the bundled intermediate certificates. I.e. the actual certificate for ccl.northwestern.edu is OK and not expired, however the server replies with a number of intermediates and CA certificates that are expired (in particular the "USERTrust RSA Certification Authority" and "AddTrust Extdernal CA Root" certificates).

When you access the site in Safari, you do not get an error, as it uses macOS' built-in certificate store. In Keychain you can validate that macOS by default has an up to date and non-expired CA certificate for "USERTrust RSA Certification Authority". Therefore you do not get any errors here.

However when you use `brew-cask`, the file is downloaded using `curl` - and `curl` does not access the same trust store. If you try to download the file manually on the command line using `curl -O` you'll get the same error.

The client-side fix for the `curl` command line is to set `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment to point to a text file that has the updated intermediates. I've tested that and you can then download without warnings.

However `brew-cask` does not seem to relay that environment variable on to `curl`, nor does it seem to respect a `cacert` line in ~/.curlrc.

The optimal way to resolve this problem is to fix the server. Update the intermediate certificate bundle associated with the web site on the server, and the problem will go away.

Comment: I do not see the SSL certificate expired too. It's the Homebrew command that's reporting the problem. The data & time are set to automatic and are correct. I am able to download the DMG and can manually install the program, however I am looking to identify and resolve the error thrown by Homebrew.

Comment: Thank you for the informative post. I think it would make a good exercise to get it resolved from the server end by reporting to the concerned.