# Installing pip ssl problem

Tags: macos, catalina, homebrew, permission

I have following problem: I'm setting up new user on my mac, as previous domain user is currently unavailable. When I try to install pip by

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

I get following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none) 

ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip

From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x1100dd7b8>:

Traceback (most recent call last):   
 
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 313, in wrapper _lib.X509_up_ref(x509) 

AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref' 

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/:  There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: 

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org ', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)) - skipping
```

I thought that as with homebrew there might be a problem with ownership of /usr/local insides, but I chown'ed it to my new user and chmod'ed to 777. What else can be done?

Comment: This seems to be a certificate error with pypi.org. Does `curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` work?

Comment: May be related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393481/homebrew-cask-download-failure-ssl-certificate-problem-certificate-has-expired/393510#393510

Comment: @nohillside yes, it works ok

Comment: Why aren’t you just installing python (equivalent to python3) with home brew? It comes with pip.